# Git Workflow for two main branches?

Tags: git, merge, version-control, git-flow

### I need to define a Git Workflow for the following case:

- There is one version currently on production (let's call it `v1.x`)
- There is also a new version (`v2.x`) that some time in the future is going to replace the current one
- They both share a lot of functionality (so far around 80% of the code is the same)
- Both versions are actively developed:

  - 60% of new features are the same for `v1.x` and `v2.x`
  - 20% is exclusively for `v1.x`, 20% only for `v2.x`
- Both versions are also being tested (prod users/testers)

  - Hotfixes for prod (`v1.x`) are sometimes needed
  - No high-priority bugs are treated like normal tasks
- Every 1-2 months a new prod version is released (eg. `v1.1` -> `v1.2`)

### Our current approach is to:

- Treat `master` as `v1.x`
- Create new branches for releases (`v1.1`, `v1.1`, ...)
- Develop common code on `master` and merge it to `v2.x`
- Develop code for `v1.x`/`v2.x` only on one of the branches and do not merge those changes to the other branch

### I've done some research and found:

- [gitflow](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) - I do not know to apply it for my case (two main branches sharing a lot of code)
- [support-branches](https://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/stable/git-branching-strategies/gitflow-examples/#support-branches) - I found it in a similar SO topic, however, I still do not know how could I use it in my case

---

### To sum it up:

Could you tell me what is the possible Git Workflow for the described case?
How should branches look like?
What should I merge? How can I merge (cherry-pick?) only commits I want and do not merge the unwanted code?

Comment: About the common code. Is that something you could share as a library in your application or is it decoupled similar way from v1.x and v2.x? Is there possible to be own repository for shared code or should it live with the same repository with different versions?

Comment: I had the same problem in the past, we had the ongoing `v1` project and we did huge refactoring on a future `v2` version.

We were using the "From Micro to Macro - GIT branching model and workflow"
https://medium.com/@br.natan/from-micro-to-macro-git-branching-model-and-workflow-8dc1b230a28e

with few minimal changes:
- before v2 is the official production version, we were thinking about it as a feature (i.e. not `master`)
- each time we had bug-fix or a new feature for `v1` we were also merging it to `v2`
- when `v2` is ready you simply move "master" to the head of `v2`

Comment: I've successfully used `git merge-base release/v1 release/v2` to determine the ideal base for new development that will be merged into both branches.

Comment: @T.Nylund it would be difficult to extract the common code to a library - it's a frontend application and you never know what designers are going to change ;) However, it could be possible for some small parts of the code. I'll check that approach, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @NatanBraslavski thank you for the branching model, I haven't seen this article before. I'm glad that such a model worked in your project, it looks like it can also work in mine :)

Comment: @JonathonReinhart `merge-base` looks really interesting. I will check how this work in a big project during this week.